# Unique values of custom class in Java Set

Tags: java, set, hashset

I expect to have only 2 elements in my `Set` but I receive 3 elements while printing! How can I define uniqueness?

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class bin {
            int a;
            int b;
            bin (int a, int b){
                this.a=a;
                this.b=b;
            }
            public boolean Equals(bin me) {
                if(this.a==me.a && this.b==me.b)
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;
            }   
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return a+" "+b;
            }
        }

        Set<bin> q= new HashSet<bin>();
        q.add(new bin(11,23));
        q.add(new bin(11,23));
        q.add(new bin(44,25));

        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never tested for uniqueness before printing

Answer (score 9):

There are two issues here

- `equals` should be lowercase and accept an `Object`
- You have to override `hashCode` as well

The modified code could look like below. Note that the implementation is far from being perfect as in `equals` you should check for null and whether a type cast is possible etc. Also `hashCode` is just an example but how to implement such things is another topic.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class bin{
            int a;
            int b;
            bin (int a, int b){
                this.a=a;
                this.b=b;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object me) {
                bin binMe = (bin)me;
                if(this.a==binMe.a && this.b==binMe.b)
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;
            }   

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return this.a + this.b;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return a+" "+b;
            }
        }

        Set<bin> q= new HashSet<bin>();
        q.add(new bin(11,24));
        q.add(new bin(11,24));
        q.add(new bin(10,25));
        q.add(new bin(44,25));

        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

---

Result:

> [11 24, 10 25, 44 25]