# Unique list of objects using HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

Can anyone tell me what the issue with my code is here? I converted the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207632/unique-values-of-custom-class-in-java-set) to use a String array instead of two ints, where I want a unique list based on the 0th index of the String array. The problem is that the overridden equals function is never getting called therefore I have repeated entries.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        class bin
        {
                String[] data;

                bin (String[] data)
                {
                    this.data=data;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean equals(Object me) 
                {
                    bin binMe = (bin)me;
                    if(this.data[0].equals(binMe.data[0])) { return true; }
                    else { return false; }
                }   

                @Override
                public int hashCode() 
                {
                    final int prime = 31;
                    int result = 1;
                    result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(data);
                    return result;              
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() 
                {
                    return data[0] + " " + data[1];
                }
        }

        Set<bin> q= new HashSet<bin>();
        q.add(new bin(new String[]{"100", "200"}));
        q.add(new bin(new String[]{"101", "201"}));
        q.add(new bin(new String[]{"101", "202"}));
        q.add(new bin(new String[]{"103", "203"}));

        System.out.println(q);
}
```

Gives an output of: [101 202, 100 200, 101 201, 103 203]

Comment: Equals is never called because the hash codes are different. Which element do you think is duplicated here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the comparison based on the first element, don't take the hash code of the full array

```
Arrays.hashCode(data);
```

Use

```
data[0].hashCode();
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that was what was happening setting the hashcode, this worked.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that the overridden equals function is never getting
>   called therefore I have repeated entries.

This is incorrect. It does get called. However, two set elements are considered equal only if for both, the `equals` method returns true and `hashCode` returns the same int. In your case, you have overriden the `equals` method to do the logical comparison based on the first element of the string array. However, you need to make sure the hashCode also returns the same `int` for two elements that you are think are logically equal.

So update the following statement in your `hashCode` implementation

from

`result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(data);`

to

`result = prime * result + data[0].hashCode();`

Answer (score 1):

The way that Hash[Set/Map]'s work, is by using the hashCode to group items into lists, and then searching these lists, this means that if all the hashCodes are unique, the list is only 1 item, and it speeds up lookup for items.

If your hashCode points to the wrong list, there are no items to check for equality, so the equals method is never called, and every item gets added, not just the unique ones.

Instead of computing the hashCode over the whole array of Strings, use `data[0].hashCode();`, as per @cricket_007's answer